# Stripe: Create restricted key that can only charge / Cannot redirect funds / pay

Tags: permissions, stripe-payments

I have to create a stripe server doing charges running in a K8s environment. The server will run in a container should be secure (famous last words...), but not as much as I would like and have no control over the issue.

In order to connect to stripe and make charges / issue invoices, the server will need a private key. Stripe supports [limited access keys](https://stripe.com/docs/keys) which seem to me a better option than a full access key. When creating a limited access key (one needs a stripe account, then can use e.g. https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys/create), there are many resources that can be set to none/read/write access.

I am wondering which is the minimal set of permissions such that the key:

- Allows for:

  - creating (and possibly removing) customers
  - creating charge items and invoices for clients.
  - allows cancelling and or refunding customers
- But **does not allow**:

  - transferring of funds to other accounts
  - any other transaction that would result on sending money / making payments

In sum, If the key is compromised, I am ok if the attacker can issue charges, get free products (=services) or refund them at will as long as he cannot steal / redirect money from the account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you need:

- `Write` for `Customer`
- `Write` for `Charge` and `PaymentIntent`

If you want to allow handling `Subscription` related matters, then set `Write` for `Subscriptions` too.

Set `None` for the rest.

Note this doesn't mean it's the best least-priviledge set of permissions. You'll still have to trial and error it to be certain that certain actions cannot be taken, i.e. try doing a payout using the key in test mode, but it should get you started on the right track.

Comment: I used that, plus write for invoices, lets see how it goes....